# Gmail alias - Automatically "send mail as" alias when alias is recipient

Tags: gmail, alias

It's all in the title, but I'll spell it out:

Let's say my primary Gmail address is `bob@gmail.com`, and my alias is `bob@bobscrabshack.com`.

I have my personal mail server forwarding mail addressed to `bob@bobscrabshack.com` to `bob@gmail.com` and I'm using my SMTP server to send mail via `bob@bobscrabhshack.com` using Gmail.

Someone sends me an email: **Crab party inquiry** to `bob@bobscrabshack.com` and I check it in Gmail. I hit reply. I want the "From:" to be automatically set to `bob@bobscrabshack.com` but by default, it is set to `bob@gmail.com`. I normally want to send mail and reply as `bob@gmail.com` except when the mail is addressed to `bob@bobscrabshack.com`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gmail Settings there is an option for this:

[image]

---

In addition, also note these settings:

[image]