# Is there a way for Google Workspace admin to set "send mail as" the original recipient in GMail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

Using a GMail's routing feature within Google Workspace for Business, I am able to set forwarding emails to 1st@my.org to 2nd@my.org. But replying to that email on 2nd@my.org's email editor (on GMail webapp on my.org), the recipient of it sees the `from` field as 2nd@my.org, not 1st@my.org.

Is there a way for an admin in the above scenario to force 2nd@my.org to reply as 1st@my.org for the emails that are sent to 1st@my.org then somehow forwarded to 2nd@my.org?

I know each user can setup their GMail editor to customize `send mail as` (e.g. [webapps.stackexchange.com#14902](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/can-gmail-automatically-base-send-from-address-on-the-to-address) and [webapps.stackexchange.com#131235](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/131235/gmail-alias-automatically-send-mail-as-alias-when-alias-is-recipient)), but I'm asking admin's feature so that each user doesn't have to bother customizing their editor.

I'm aware that Google Workspace comes with multiple routing options. For now, I'm using `Default Routing` but other routing option can be considered. I'm an admin in a small org that uses Google Workspace for nonprofit.

---

UPDATE 2024/03/26 To clarify, the solution doesn't have to be implemented in Google Workspace's rounting feature.

Comment: Many email clients do this, but you dont usd a forward. Instead grab enails from both addresses. These can br displayed together or separately

Comment: No. What you are asking for can't be done.  You need to manage "send as" options within the mail client. It isn't related to email routing.

Comment: @Blindspots Thanks. As I updated OP, the solution can be implemented anywhere. I'm not limiting to email routing.